# Connecting and using button inside table with a custom cell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm facing a little problem. I have a table with 2 classes. using `UIViewcontroller` as the root view and inside it i have as a child a `UITableViewCell`. i made custom a cell and i have buttons inside them.

**Problem:** how do i connect and use the buttons?

I have tried some stuff and workarounds that are mentioned down.. but with no use. Lastly i got so dispirit that i was gonna try to pot a label and use its tag to make it act as a button if that was even possible.

1) I tried connecting the button to the root view but it resulted a storyboard error when building.

2) I tried connecting the button to the `UITableViewCell`. Its okay but in the the code that i want to use inside the `-(IBAction)btnclicked` for the button which is:

```
-(IBAction)btnclicked
{
        profileViewController *second = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AnotherView"];
        [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

when i use this code i get these error messages

for the first line inside the method:
Property 'storyboard' not found on object of type 'AnotherView'

for the second line:
No visible @interface for 'OtherUsersCell' declares the selector 'presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:'

im using the above code to connect my views instead of storyboard segues.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @staticVoidMan still no us. i get same errors. Thanks tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!. here's what i did, first in this  method:

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
```

As seen bellow, i gave my button a tag (in my case -16) and determined a selector that points to the method that should run when the button is taped, in my case the method name is `ButtonClicked`

```
UIButton *Button= (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag: -16];
Button.tag = -16;
[Button addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Below is my method code:

```
-(void) ButtonClicked
{
        buyViewController *second = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyOtherView"];
        [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I faced the same problem with different kind of objects and so far for all the cases i used tag which can be assigned to any object in a view from the Attribute inspector. I hop this helps anyone who is facing the same problem.